# Is $A(x, y, z) = (xy + z, yz - x)$ a linear function?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is this a Linear function? If yes, what is its matrix?

$$A:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^2, A(x, y, z) = (xy + z, yz - x);$$

Since they are all first degree variables, i think that this is a linear function.

If yes, thank its matrix should be:

$$\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$$
Thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: Done. Anyway i don't think this is the right solution

Comment: Remember: A function $f:A\to B$ is linear if $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ and $f(kx)=kf(x)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your answer is very much lacking. You simply say "If yes, then its matrix should be [0,0][0,0]".

That is a very bad way of thinking in mathematics that can lead you to a lot of trouble. The problem is that a matrix is only defined for a **linear** function. What you did was immediatelly find a matrix before showing the function is linear (is it? Did you try to prove that it is/is not?).

That is the equivalent of trying to drive your car without filling it up with gas first.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
Try computing $A(1,1,0), A(1,0,0),$ and $A(0,1,0)$. If $A$ were a linear function, you would get
$$
A(1,1,0) = A[(1,0,0) + (0,1,0)] = A(1,0,0) + A(0,1,0).
$$
Is this true?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use, say, that $A(1,1,1)=(2,0)$ but $A(2,2,2)=(6,2),\;$ so
$A(2,2,2)\ne2 A(1,1,1)$.